# How to read NSCR1000 data files?

Tags: file-format, osx, binary-format

Terminal app on OSX stores the information about its windows and content in its state files in `Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState`.

I did the backup of the file before the crash to be able to restore my data, but I don't know how to read it now (as Terminal refuses to use it). It starts with: `NSCR1000` as below:

```
$ hexdump -Cn8 ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/data.data
00000000  4e 53 43 52 31 30 30 30                           |NSCR1000|
```

It's used by `windows.plist` file which can be decoded by:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o windows.plist windows.plist
```

What kind of method I can use to read that `.data` file? Or where do I start?

```
$ strings data.data | head -10
NSCR1000
p+5v
0>[t
kJX6X
@NSCR1000
```

This file is automatically generated by Terminal app when you start and start typing something, so the terminal data is stored there.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on exact steps to take? I believe i've stored/copied the needed files, but can't make sense of this seemingly easy statement:
"Quit Terminal, copy the contents of this folder from your backup, then open Terminal." from this SO: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326108/restore-terminal-tabs-with-session-history Files are copied, where do i put em? I'm using Zsh via terminal app..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is encrypted with AES so you will need the keys from `windows.plist` to decode.

The format is (all stored in big-endian):

```
offset  value
0-3     magic ('NSCR' for PersistentUIRecord)
4-7     version (either '1000' or '0006')
8-11    NSWindowID (used to lookup 128-bit AES key stored in windows.plist)
12-15   record length (including from 0 to xxx)
16-xxx  encrypted binary plist data
```

There may be multiple records stored in a file consecutively.

Similar approach AppKit framework is using to decipher the `data.data` file. The most relevant code base to look at is the `+[NSPersistentUIRecord parseOneRecordFromReadBlock:withDecryptionKeys:]` block which parses each record in the `data.data` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question I have: how did you learn those details?

Comment: I just poked around the AppKit framework reversing how it deciphered the `data.data` file. The most relevant code base to look at is the                                              `+[NSPersistentUIRecord parseOneRecordFromReadBlock:withDecryptionKeys:]` block which parses  each record in the `data.data` file.

Comment: That sounds great like it was so easy thing to do! Awesome inspiration to learn more about RE. Thanks again for answer.

Comment: I am not sure how kind you are to be asked but that would be truly great if you could share your mastery in a blog post. I highly encourage you to do that as it would be very interesting reading for everyone especially if you could explain your technique of finding the right answer in a simple way. So many developers could benefit from your experience, please do!